# Error running Tensorflow/Keras on Dask/Docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have this Docker container built with the image provided by the Dask project: `FROM daskdev/dask`

I install Tensorflow and Keras in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip3 install tensorflow
RUN pip3 install scikeras
```

In my python code I try to train a Keras model:

```
niceties = dict(verbose=False)
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model,  lr=0.1,  momentum=0.9,  
                        loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), **niceties)

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=500)   # <--- here it throws the error


def build_model(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(50,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

The error says that the cuda/nvidia library is not found. That's fine, I don't want to run Tensorflow with GPU, how to tell Tensorflow not to use it?

> 2021-12-23 01:45:33.044350: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
> /pyenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clidriver/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc
>
> 2021-12-23 01:45:33.044395: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to
> cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
>
> 2021-12-23 01:45:33.044418: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver
> does not appear to be running on this host (9b318a7a9609):
> /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
>
> 2021-12-23 01:45:33.044625: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX2 FMA
>
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the
> appropriate compiler flags.

Comment: I have to use the `daskdev/dask`  image provided by the Dask project. Also, I run this with `docker compose`

Comment: This is a warning, not an error, you can ignore it, it will run on the CPU.